# Problem running Jest using CLS with async functions

Tags: javascript, async-await, jestjs

I can't seem to get CLS to work with Jest.

The following code:

```
export {}
const { promises: fs } = require('fs')

describe('CLS tests', () => {
  test('Can test CLS', async () => {
    var createNamespace = require('cls-hooked').createNamespace
    var session = createNamespace('session')
    session.run(async function () {
      await fs.readFile('package.json', 'utf-8')
      console.log('I cant log this')
    })
  })
})
```

Results in the following error:

> Cannot log after tests are done. Did you forget to wait for something
> async in your test?
> Attempted to log "I cant log this".

Why is it that my test appears to be exiting early?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to abstract out the `asynchronous` operations.  I tried this on my system and it works.

```js
const {promises: fs} = require('fs')

const runSession = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const createNamespace = require('cls-hooked').createNamespace
  const session = createNamespace('session')
  session.run(() => {
    fs.readFile('package.json', 'utf-8')
        .then(resolve)
  })
})

describe('CLS tests', () => {
  test('Can test CLS', async () => {
    const result = await runSession()
    console.log('hello')
    console.log(result)
    expect(result).toBeTruthy()
    console.log('after expect...')
  })
})
```

[image]

Good Luck...

Comment: Most welcom @JamieAlexander :) .  If this answers your question; please `accept` the anwer by clicking on the tick-mark on the left-hand side near the top of the answer.